# Can't recieve information from my blogger site using a Get request and v3 API

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, blogger

When I do an GET to the test google site in the docs the blogger documentation the request works fine.

When I do a GET to my personal site I get this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

Working:
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953?key=AIzaSyA-6DkaL7Ff_U5Xwm4c_0XoCA_I4G1E24U

Non working:
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/657661307303?key=AIzaSyA-6DkaL7Ff_U5Xwm4c_0XoCA_I4G1E24U

I DO have the blogger v3 API enabled. My key is working as shown above. My blog is set to public and  can be  viewed here:
http://mutant1098.blogspot.com/

Also I see the failed requests coming into my bloggers dashboard.

I don't understand what the issue is. Why is it working on google bloggers main site but not my personal site.

I scoured the API dashboard for any permissions issues but couldn't find any that looked like the  problem.

Thanks in advance for any guidance. This looks like a great platform just wish it was either easier or better documented.

Answer (score 0):

Your blog ID must be incorrect, because the call to [getByUrl](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/blogs/getByUrl) works:

https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/byurl?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmutant1098.blogspot.ca%2F&key=AIzaSyA-6DkaL7Ff_U5Xwm4c_0XoCA_I4G1E24U